# Loops to generate pairs of values from 0 to 8 to make 3x3 blocks

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, range

I am trying to write a loop to generate pairs of values from 0 up to 8. For each value above the block, I have to generate a second value between 0 and 8. I must also have spacing between every 3x3 block.
I have attached a picture of what the output is supposed to look like since I can't describe the output in words.

[image]

I tried playing around with the end and sep on the loops, but to no avail. I am not to familiar with Python but here is what I have tried.

```
for i in range(0,9):
    for j in range(0, 9):
        print (i,j, sep = ',', end = ' ')
```

From this code, I am able to generate the pairs I need, but I am just clueless as to how to space them.
Anything is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working fine according to me:

```py
for i in range (9):
        k = 0

        if i % 3 == 0:
            print()

        for j in range (9):

            if k % 9 == 0:
                print()

            if j % 3 == 2:
                print(i, j, sep = ',', end = '  ')

            else:
                print(i, j, sep = ',', end = ' ')
            k += 1
```

It's kind of difficult for me to explain it's working, but once you see it you'll get it right away

Comment: Yeah this works, I see why. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1):

A more versatile approach: we create a function that takes a list of strings, a separator and a chunk size, and joins each chunk of strings with the separator.

We create the list of values, join them 3 by 3 with a single space to get triplets, join the triplets 3 by 3 with more spaces to get lines, join the lines 3 by 3 to get line blocks, and join the line blocks with double newlines to get the table.

The code is shorter than the explanation:

```
from itertools import product

def join_by(strings, sep, n=3):
    """Return a list of strings obtained by joining chunks of n strings with sep"""
    return [sep.join(chunk) for chunk in (out[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(out), n))]

values = [f'{row},{col}' for row, col in product(range(9), repeat=2)]

triplets = join_by(values, ' ', 3) 
lines = join_by(triplets, '   ', 3)
line_groups = join_by(lines, '\n', 3)
table = join_by(line_groups, '\n\n', 3)[0]
```

Output:

```
print(table)

0,0 0,1 0,2   0,3 0,4 0,5   0,6 0,7 0,8
1,0 1,1 1,2   1,3 1,4 1,5   1,6 1,7 1,8
2,0 2,1 2,2   2,3 2,4 2,5   2,6 2,7 2,8

3,0 3,1 3,2   3,3 3,4 3,5   3,6 3,7 3,8
4,0 4,1 4,2   4,3 4,4 4,5   4,6 4,7 4,8
5,0 5,1 5,2   5,3 5,4 5,5   5,6 5,7 5,8

6,0 6,1 6,2   6,3 6,4 6,5   6,6 6,7 6,8
7,0 7,1 7,2   7,3 7,4 7,5   7,6 7,7 7,8
8,0 8,1 8,2   8,3 8,4 8,5   8,6 8,7 8,8
```